# Run Active Record Class Method from Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, methods

I have method `def repay_loans` in `class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base`, how can I run it in the rails console.

I tried Loan.repay_loans but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `repay_loans' for Loan (call 'Loan.connection' to establish a connection):Class
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey as Per your code def repay_loans is object method you are tried to call it by class so it will gives you error

you can call it by creating object

```
 l = Loan.new
 l.repay_loans
```

otherwise if you want it on class level then you can define your method as class method like:

```
def self.repay_loans
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to run an instance method as a class method.

If you want to have a class method then change your definition to

```
def self.repay_loans
  ...
end
```

Otherwise you'll need to call the `repay_loans` with the correct object (instance of `Loan` class)

Comment: If I change the class name to self.repay_loans I still get the same error when running Loan.repay_loans.

Comment: not the class name, the method definition. most probably you need to reload your console.

Comment: @Pabi you needs to reload your console by using reload! method after change in class